# Taxonomy term title not displayed as page title in Panels when paged

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, panels

I have use case where for some terms, on the term pages (where nodes with that term are displayed) where for selected terms, I need to display an image instead of the title. To (try to) do this, I've done the following steps:

1. Add field_image to the vocabulary.
2. Upload images for selected terms
3. Enabled the built in taxonomy term panel page.
4. Created a content pane in the built in taxonomy term view that passes the tid.
5. Created a term view with a content pane display with term name and field_image as fields.
6. Hide term name from display, and set term name to be displayed in the No Results settings for field_image.
7. Add the content pane to the panel page display above the content pane from the taxonomy term view.

This all works great - on the first page. However, once I use the pager (from the view) to go to any subsequent pages, the page title (i.e. the term name or image) disappears. Looking at the page source, you can see that the panel pane with the term title (step 5 above) is not added at all, which makes sense, since there aren't multiple pages of term titles.

Is there a way to do what I need with the Views and Panels UI, or will I need to wield some code fu to replace the name with the image selectively?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pager IDs are conflicting.  Adjust the pager settings for one of the views to have a pager ID of 1 rather than 0.

[image]